# Why does my mac suddenly have long pauses until I restart it?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, performance

I will wake my mac up from sleep. I enter the password and push enter; it takes 10 seconds to unlock. All actions are delayed; a chrome tab will show blank before rendering the page. Clicking on the apple to `Restart...` shows the pinwheel (before completing and allowing me to restart).

All actions (e.g. running git in a terminal window) are paused before executing. The CPU isn't running high. I don't see anything strange apart from the pauses. After restarting things are OK again.

This happens infrequently, though it has been going on for at least a year.

I'm running currently 10.14.6 (18G95).

The machine is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015).
Disk is SSD.

Comment: WHat sort of disk do you have and how much swap space is in use?

Comment: It also would be interesting if you disabled all network and repeat the test. Hard to tell if its waiting for network or not until you isolate the Mac. Would hate for you to dive into tuning the os and apps if you just have a lot of pending network timeouts when you wake from sleep / don’t let power nap keep things current in sleep.

Comment: @Mark I've update some machine info in the question. I can check swap next time it starts freezing; right now it's at 2.51 GB out of 16.

Comment: @bmike I'll definitely try that next time it happens.